# getContext() method returns null in fragment. Is it a good idea to keep the context in a variable? I want to understand the pros and cons

Tags: android, android-context

What I do is

Approach 1:

```
public View onCreateView(.....){
     context = getContext();
}
```

I am using this context object wherever I need. Is this the right approach or I should use `getContext != null` and use the value returned by `getContext()`. Also I understand that I can get the context from `getActivity()` but it will also return null if 'getContext()' is returning null.

As an alternative I can do this every time I need the context.

Approach 2:

```
if(getActivity() != null){
      //use getActivity() here
}
```

I want to understand which one is a better way and why?

Comment: `getActivity()`

Comment: Second way is better approach. Storing `Context` as local variable can be harmful because, `Fragment` has it's own lifecycle and we can't predict at which stage context becomes **null** *(`getActivity()` or `getContext()`)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getActivity()` and `getContext()` both will return null if your fragment is not attached to an activity/context. If they are returning null, I won't suggest using any previously stored value as the stored context may have been detached and can lead to memory leaks.

Generally, you get a context after the fragment is attached. You can store the context in the `onAttach(Context)` callback.

```java
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.context = context;
}
```

However, be sure to set it to null whenever the fragment gets detached to avoid memory leaks.

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    this.activity = null;
    super.onDetach();
}
```

There are no cons of storing the context in a variable that I can think of except you need to be careful about fragment state changes. The `onDetach()` call takes care of that.

Answer (score 3):

In your fragment override the function

```
private Context mContext;

@override
void onAttach(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
```

This is how you’ll get context in fragment as it is never recommended to pass context to fragments and adapters from activities.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you need to get context and keep it, i recommend create a static variable on your current activity (if you only use one activity)

```
//if use only one Activity
private static Context context;
public static Context getRunningContext() {
    return context;
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    this.context=getApplicationContext();
}
```

or use getActivity() instead.

```
    Context context;
   public View onCreateView(.....){
   context = getActivity();
}
```

Comment: Storing context in static variables will your app fall into memory leaks. Avoid it!